# How to make a filter in react-select using the value of another react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm creating a solution using a [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/) and that a select should contain only the options it does not contain in the other. Ex

```
import React from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

const list = [
  { label: 'foo', value: 1 },
  { label: 'bar', value: 2 },
  { label: 'bin', value: 3 },
]

export default Test extends React.Component {
  render = () => (
    <>
      <Select ref="a" options={list} />
      <Select ref="b" options={list} filterOption={o => /* devo omitir "a" */} />
    </>
  )
}
```

What do I need to do to have a `<Select ref="b" />` filtered by the value of another `<Select ref="a" />` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer above from Laura breaks the filtering as you're writing a custom filterOption function (If you don't want your Select to be filterable then it's probably ok).

A simpler solution would be to just apply a simple filter on the `options` you pass through instead to the second Select instead.

```
const options = [
  { label: "foo", value: 1 },
  { label: "bar", value: 2 },
  { label: "bin", value: 3 }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value1: false,
      value2: false
    };
  }

  onChange = option => {
    if (this.state.value2.value === option.value) {
      this.setState({
        value1: option,
        value2: false
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ value1: option });
    }
  };

  onChange2 = option => {
    this.setState({ value2: option });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          onChange={this.onChange}
          options={options}
          value={this.state.value1}
        />
        <Select
          onChange={this.onChange2}
          options={options.filter(
            option => option.value !== this.state.value1.value
          )}
          value={this.state.value2}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-56669201-k2idq?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your goal you need to store your select values in the state in order to compare it with the options in `filterOption` like the following example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value1: false,
      value2: false
    };
  }

  filterOption = ({ label, value, data }, string) => {
    if (this.state.value1 === data) {
      return false;
    } else if (string) {
      return label.includes(string) || value.toString().includes(string);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };

  onChange = option => {
    this.setState({ value1: option });
  };

  onChange2 = option => {
    this.setState({ value2: option });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          onChange={this.onChange}
          options={options}
          value={this.state.value1}
        />
        <Select
          filterOption={this.filterOption}
          onChange={this.onChange2}
          options={options}
          value={this.state.value2}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-56669201-5tzih).

Comment: This answer breaks the filtering on the select.

Comment: @Dairylee have patched my answer to include the original filter function